# Change the null values ​of multiple lists that only differ by a number

Tags: r, for-loop, null, assign

I want to change the null values ​​of multiple lists that only differ by a number. In this example I have 3 lists: "a1", "a2" and "a3", and I want to change their null values for "THERE'S NO VALUE". I've tried with a for loop using "paste" function, but it doesn't run. This is a simplied version of my code:

```
a1<-list(NULL, "a","b")
a2<-list("d", NULL,"m")
a3<-list("k", NULL,"l")

for (i in 1:3){
  var<-paste("a", i, sep = "")
  var[var=='NULL']<-"THERE'S NO VALUE"
}
```

Also I've tried with assign function, but It changes all variables, and I only want to change the null element of each one (I suspect why, but I don't know how to change the function to work):

```
for (i in 1:3){
  var<-paste("a", i, sep = "")
  assign(var,var[var=='NULL']<-"THERE'S NO VALUE")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `mget` to get the objects in a `list`, then loop over the `list` with `lapply`, replace the elements that are `NULL` with the new value and then if needed, use `list2env` to change the object values in the global env

```
list2env(lapply(mget(paste0("a", 1:3)), function(x) {
     x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- "THERE'S NO VALUE"
     x}), 
    .GlobalEnv)
```

-Now check the objects

```
a1
[[1]]
[1] "THERE'S NO VALUE"

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] "b"

a2
[[1]]
[1] "d"

[[2]]
[1] "THERE'S NO VALUE"

[[3]]
[1] "m"

a3
[[1]]
[1] "k"

[[2]]
[1] "THERE'S NO VALUE"

[[3]]
[1] "l"
```